# How to change this formula to do cell referencing

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to pull some financial earning data from marketwatch website.
No matter how i try i can't seem to do a cell referencing(say cell B2) for this formula.
Desperately need some help, thank you very much!!

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/AIG/financials","table",1)
```

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting a question.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "cell referencing."  Do you want to store the url in a cell and reference it in IMPORTHTML? Or do you want to reference data after you've imported it?

Comment: thanks for the reply, sorry its not clear enough.
say i have a dropdown box(cell B3) where i store all the stock symbol like AIG, C, BAC etc.
can i amend the formula to reference data after i've imported it? So that my formula will look something like 
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/quote.ashx?t="&B3","table",1)

thank you again for the help

Answer (score 1):

it will need to look like this (note the double quote placement):

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/quote.ashx?t="&B3, "table", 1)
```